# cuML functions running on DASK? and dask_cudf manipulation?

Tags: python, dataframe, dask, rapids

How to run dask_cuML (logistic regression for example) on a large dataset, dask_cudf?

I can not run cuML on my cudf dataframe because dataset is large so "OUT of MEMORY" as soon as I try anything. Bright side is I got 4 GPUs to use with dask_cudf.

Does anybody know steps to use to run logistic regression for example on a dask_cudf dataframe?

About my cudf and cuml logistic function:

```
type(gdf)
cudf.core.dataframe.DataFrame

logreg = cuml.LogisticRegression(penalty='none', tol=1e-6, max_iter=10000)
logreg.fit(gdf[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']], gdf['Z'])
```

My thoughts -- in steps: (Not Working!)

1- Convert gdf cudf to dask_cudf.

```
  ddf = dask_cudf.from_cudf(gdf, npartitions=2) -- what's the number of partitions?
```

2- `meta_dtypes = dict(zip(ddf.columns, ddf.dtypes))`

3-

```
def logistic_regression(gdf):
              return logreg.fit(gdf[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']], gdf['Z'])
```

4- `ddf  = ddf .map_partitions(logistic_regression, meta=meta_dtypes)`

```
ddf.compute().persist()
```

Any suggestions or insights are appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

thank you for trying out `cuml`! The official release of cuml doesn't have logistic regression for multiple gpu yet (coming soon!) . I'm implementing a workaround using `dask-glm` and `cupy`. I'll publish my notebook in this thread once it is ready. Here are the general steps:

1. if your dataset is too large, I recommend reading the csv files using dask_cudf instead of converting cudf dataframe to dask_cudf. let's say there are multiple csv files, you can read them with

```
ddf = dask_cudf.read_csv("*.csv")
```

2. convert dask cudf dataframe to dask arrays by calling

```
X = ddf[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']].values
y = ddf['Z'].values
```

where each chunk of the dask array is a `cupy` array.

3. fit the dask array with my version of dask-glm logistic regression.

```
from dask_glm.estimators import LogisticRegression
clf = LogisticRegression()
clf.fit(X,y)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply Carl. Yes, I agree it is ideal to create dask dataframe directly from csv, but the only reason why I was trying to create ddf from cudf is because I apply many transformations that are not in dask yet, for example cudf.DataFrame.one_hot_encoding and factorize method, etc... How would you approach this?
Great, you guys are planning to implement LogisticReg next, I'd gladly help implement other algos.. I really enjoy the power of cuml, especially w combined w dask :) what's git repo? https://github.com/rapidsai/dask-cuml?

Comment: All of it is in cuML now. There's an issue board if you want to grab a future feature and start working on it. We welcome new contributors.